# javax.imageio.IIOException :Can't create an ImageInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to get the height and width of all the images in my "Images" folder. Unfortunately, i keep receiving this "Can't create an ImageInputStream!" error. How can i solve it?

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create an ImageInputStream!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1280)
at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:34)
```

This is my full code

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

     try {
           File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator")+ "Images");
           BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
           int height = image.getHeight();
           int width = image.getWidth();
           System.out.println("Width : "+ width);
           System.out.println("Height : "+ height);

          } catch (IOException ioe) {
               ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's because you are not opening a file but opening a directory instead.

```
File directory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") 
         + System.getProperty("file.separator")+ "Images";

for(File file: directory.listFiles()) {
     BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Since this code only works for one picture, How can I read the image properties for all the image in my "Images" folder?

Comment: You should add a FileFilter so that only image files are processed.

Comment: This is an old post, but for what it's worth: Do File.listFiles, then loop through the files, read each one, and extract the data you need.